Unit testing functionality that uses the RazorFormat plugin
We have an endpoint that uses RazorFormat to render some html and we are wanting to unit test it.
When we construct a RazorFormat the format is missing the ViewEngine which is of type IRazorViewEngine
I have tried extending the plugin to allow setting the ViewEngine by fetching IRazorViewEngine but it still runs into an issue with ITempDataProvider being null.
Is there a way to instantiate the RazorFormat class while passing in the IRazorViewEngine and any requirements it has without standing up an apphost?
If it does require an app host , what is the simplest way to end up with a functional RazorFormat class ?

IRazorViewEngine is registered by MVC, so requires an App configured with MVC. It's not really unit testable, you'd need at least an AppHost with MVC Services registered, e.g:
public override void Configure(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}

We have an Integration Test that uses Razor Format in ServiceStack.Server.Tests/AppHost.cs which has Razor Integration tests in StatelessAuthRazorTests.cs
